# How do I close a question on Teams for a reason other than duplicate?

Tags: support, close-reasons, stack-overflow-for-teams

When I open the close dialog on a Teams site, the only option is to close as duplicate.

However, I've seen some users be able to close questions for other reasons, such as "unclear what you're asking" and "off-topic".

How can this be done? Is it possible for some users, or are they exploiting some workaround?

(Side note: the off-topic close reason has the incorrect wording "This question does not appear to be about on-topic, within the scope defined in the help center". This implies to me that it might be an unsupported workaround.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can close posts by manually setting a close flag via the still exposed endpoints (hidden from the UI but still there). One POC is running the highlighted lines from this [mod script](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/AdditionalPostModActions.user.js#L77-L88) in your browser dev console except you replace data where appropriate (for instance url should have your team specific URL before the /flag endpoint to avoid accidentally voting on Stack Overflow questions, reasons should be replaced with the documented-in-script ones etc.)

*Disclaimer: This feature is not officially supported in any way by the Stack Exchange team and many of these endpoints are in the process of being disabled. Use at your own risk.*