# Add more close reasons to a private team

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, stack-overflow-for-teams

We have a private stack overflow team. When there is an invalid question, we only have the option to close it as a duplicate of other question.

When we looked at the settings of the team (from an admin account of course) we didn't find any option to select which close reasons are shown. Please let us use other close reasons. We don't need manual ones. The ones from main stack overflow would be just fine.

There is a workaround described in [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377878/how-do-i-close-a-question-on-teams-for-a-reason-other-than-duplicate). Using the old API endpoints. However this is not a supported way of doing it and forcing users to write their own app that would send requests is not cool.

[image: Our close reasons list]

Comment: I'm a member of "SE community"-related Teams, so maybe I don't get the reasoning for this request. But may I know why you want to have it closed instead of deleted, considering Teams is fully under your organization control?

Comment: Same reason as for global stack overflow. Forcing a user to delete a question or just delete it for him doesn't teach the community (your company) how to work with questions, how to write a good question and what not to ask.

Having a close reason shows exactly what's wrong with that question while also allowing users to find this question instead of asking a new one etc.

Comment: Most SO Teams moderator tools are hidden from sight but actually accessible with POST requests.

Comment: I think using technical workarounds like hand-crafted POST requests are precisely what OP is looking to avoid.  This is a paid product that shouldn't require a professional developer to admin.  Not exposing an admin interface to this feature seems like an oversight.

Comment: Certainly a lot of white space is available!

Comment: Pavel, You can basically forget about getting design and UI issues fixed. Stack Overflow fails miserably in those areas. The responses should shed some light on some of the underlying problems.

Comment: @AndrewT. if you can't access / add close reasons, how is it fully under his organizations control? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. You're right that only having *"duplicate of..."* as a possible close reason can make closing Teams questions kind of awkward.

We've added *"off-topic"* as a new reason when closing question on Teams and you can start using it as of now.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the ones on the main site and let them be configurable?

Comment: The default ones we have on the main sites are tailored to communities that have a clearly defined scope. They don't really fit for Teams as they are. Our custom and configurable reasons come with a lot of opinions for how public sites are run, too. Adopting this for Teams would come with quite some complexity and we thought it'd be better to go for the simple solution here.

Comment: Thanks. Can we expect more reasons to come? Primarily `Unclear what you're asking` would be good for the posts that possibly aren't even a question (that's what we're fighting with mostly). I believe `Too broad` would be generally applicable too.