# Make moderator tools more accessible in SO Teams

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, moderator-tools

Nearly all moderator tools are hidden from SO Teams team admins.
If you have a SO team open `https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team-url}/admin/links`.
Some hidden tools:

- Lock posts
- Add post notices
- Invalidate bounties
- Access the moderator menu
- Flagging
- More close reasons

Here are some hidden ones that should definitely be removed:

- Contact the CM team (never used it)
- User annotations

Here are some that should be added:

- More reputation for tools in SO teams (default for all of them is 1 reputation) 
  <sup>(optional:make it adjustable)</sup>
- Full access to the moderator help center

Can these be made more accessible?

Related:
[Add more close reasons to a private team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384185)

Comment: what's your use-case for this?

Comment: Huh. If you test them, then we'd have to fix the bugs. And the bugs are probably skewed pretty heavily towards things that just don't work in Teams, for which an obvious fix would be just hiding the relevant tool in Teams. I smell an efficiency...

Comment: @Shog9 No bugs in there. Really.

Comment: I've created a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8949/79306) for this purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When Teams Alpha was first launched, the moderation tools was completely broken. After asking the Stack Overflow dev team to prevent this, they were hidden from the system. Therefore, the tools are hidden after request from the actual users of Teams.

As Jon [mentions in an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364336/4099593)

> At launch we don't plan on having diamond moderators. We're removing links to many of the moderator tools and we're going to be removing the routes too. None of them should have an effect on the main site, but some links from a channel might go to a page on the main site so be careful. Look at the URL to be sure.

Similarly, Adam said this:

> As Jon said, there are no plans for Teams having moderators at the moment. We're waiting to gather some feedback on which tools would actually be useful and necessary instead of just replicating all of what public SO has as is. If nothing else, most of our tools are unintuitive on the best of days.

What we need to do here is to prevent users from pen testing Teams in order to find holes in the actual moderation system. This can be done by just removing all of the /admin routes.

The tools are hidden in Teams for a reason. Let us not bring them back. There is literally no use for any of those which you mention, except additional close reasons which is already mentioned.

Answer (score -5):

As you said, these features are still there - just hidden by the UI and with no link or otherwise.  However, the endpoints and most pages still exist.  I've created a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8949/79306) to show them.

Comment: Well I sort of appreciate the linking, but I feel like posting on this old question should not have been done (Instead, a comment could have helped more.). Well it would have been better without the downvotes too, but there is nothing we can do.