# Teams bug causes "off-topic" close reason to show twice in close review filtering options

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, close-reasons, stack-overflow-for-teams

This has already been reported in [this Meta Stack Exchange bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327757/off-topic-twice-in-filter-menu), but as the bug has to do with Teams, I'm reposting this here since the Teams development team is active here. While I don't have enough reputation to access the Close Votes queue on this site, I could reproduce it there, where I do.

As [Fabby](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/275497/fabby) reports, when filtering close reasons in the Close Votes queue, the "off-topic" option shows up twice:

[image: Off-topic twice]

[Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) did some investigation by [querying the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1042309/closereasontypes) for the full list of close reasons, and it looks like there is a new close reason with ID 201 that is supposed to be an "off-topic" close reason for Teams (still referred to as "Channels" in the database):

[image: Reason 201: "off-topic (channels)"]

It appears that the team is implementing an official "off-topic" close reason option for Teams, possibly in response to too many users using [unsupported workarounds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377878/how-do-i-close-a-question-on-teams-for-a-reason-other-than-duplicate) to get around the fact that the only closing option was as duplicate. However, I'm a member of a Team, and I don't see this new option; I still only see the duplicate reason as the only option.

Shadow Wizard also found that the second "off-topic" checkbox in the filter dialog does indeed correspond to this new reason 201; can that checkbox please be removed? The close reason is not currently in use on Teams, but it's triggering a bug on *public* Q&A.

Comment: Out of interest, I did exploit this workaround to see how the close reason would look like: [here's how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqDyK.png).

Comment: Why are there 3 *off topic*s? Ids: `1`, `102` and `201`?

Comment: @Lino Reason 1 refers to the old "off topic" (space, not hyphen) close reason from [prior to 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op); that's a static reason with no options for sub-reasons. 102 is the new "off-topic" close reason currently in use and supporting sub-reasons. 201 is a new close reason that hasn't existed before, and based on the name and my test above it's likely to only be implemented on internal Teams sites.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention - good catch spotting this as a Teams issue. The problem is fixed.

Comment: @HamVocke When will this new close reason roll out? As I said, despite this new close reason showing up in the DB, the only closing option I can see is as duplicate.

Comment: @gparyani will go out pretty soon. some final rounds of testing before we'll activate it on production ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(To answer this one properly, too - I've already answered the [question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327757/off-topic-twice-in-filter-menu))*

Thank you for spotting this. This was indeed an unintended side-effect when introducing a new close reason for Teams. I didn't have in mind that our moderator tools consider all close reasons when showing filter options.

Sorry for the confusion. The problem's fixed now and the second off-topic option is gone.